# Exact matching in R for a word

Tags: r, match

I have a dataset named tweets_data which captures details of a tweet using the Rtweet package. One of the columns named text captures the text of the tweet. I am trying to match if the text of the tweet has any of the words mentioned in the code below. I was facing issues with the word "ad" since words like dad, adverb, bad etc. were also getting captured. I used "\bad\b" instead of "ad" and it improved the results but it is still capturing some tweets where there is no use of word "ad". I want to match for exact word "ad".

```
words = c("endorsement","advertisement","sponsored","\\bad\\b","sponsored content","advert","paid partnership")
x <- sapply(words, function(x) grepl(tolower(x), tolower(tweets_data$text)))
tweets_data$Words <- apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(names(i)[i], collapse = ","))
tweets_data$Count <- apply(x, 1, function(i) sum(i))
```

Comment: This should have worked, if it doesn't work for you can you create a small reproducible example so that we can check what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ for starting and $ for ending.

```
"^ad$", "^AD$"
```